# Geometric progression of terms involving floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Which positive real number has the property that $x ,\lfloor x\rfloor,$ and $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ form a geometric progression (in that order)?

Comment: Assume that $x = 1 + \varepsilon$ with $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. What is $\lfloor x\rfloor$? What is $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$? What does it mean that these numbers form a geometric sequence?

Answer (score 3):

For $x=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$, since we have
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2},\ \ \lfloor x\rfloor=1,\ \ x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}$$
we have
$$\lfloor x\rfloor=xr,\ \ \ x-\lfloor x\rfloor=xr^2$$
where $r=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Let $ x = a + k $, where $ a = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor $ and $ 0 \le k < 1 $. Then, we want $$ \frac {k}{a} = \frac {a}{a + k} \implies ak + k^2 = a^2, $$so $ak+k^2$ needs to be an integer.